# Private beta and invite only application launch using facebook authentication

Tags: php, python, facebook-graph-api

We have a scenario where application is scheduled for a private beta launch. Also, application will only have login via facebook facility.

As per the app workflow, we will initially send invite to a few selected users who will then authenticate using facebook. Authenticated users can establish connections with their facebook contacts within application context. As they establish these connections, application will send out invites visible only to connected contacts of the user. Invited contacts can then login into the application using facebook auth.

What I have tried and where the problem is:

1. **Notifications:** As per [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests), only canvas applications can send light weight notifications. Even if we decide to launch application within facebook canvas, notifications can be sent to user contacts (those contacts who have not already authorised application) only via User-generated requests (i.e. via Request dialogs). This doesn't go well with application requirements and needs i.e. showing a request dialog every time user establish a connection with it's contact doesn't seems like a nice user experience to us.
2. **Wall Posts:** Another possibility is to post invitation on contact wall. However, facebook doesn't seems to provide an ability to [control privacy of posted feeds](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) on contacts wall. Documentation says `Post privacy settings (can only be specified if the Timeline being posted on belongs to the User creating the Post)`

Is there a legal way to launch application under private beta / invite only using facebook authentication mechanism ? Since application is targeted for a specific kind of user group, we would like to control who gets to try the application.

Comment: Hi, this might not completely help you, but why not add the users as test users of your app, and put your app in sandbox mode on facebook ? that way, you can control who gets to use it..also, you can configure the app activity privacy in a way that it doesn't display on the users' NF or timeline (i.e. visibile only to the user)

Comment: We wanted to invite a bunch of selected users who in turn will send out invites via connections they make in app context. So adding users to sandbox isn't really an option. We are finally using something like "login with facebook to request invite", that doesn't hurt us and allow us to achieve what we wanted to. People can register but unless admins approve their profile (via app connection invite users will get auto approved), they won't be able to do much on the app apart from general browsing.